# How to use batch normalization layer's training option in Sequential layer?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to put batch normalization in the sequential layer for clean code.

But I found that I don't know how to use the batch normalization layer's training option if I put it in Sequential.

For example :

```
class OriginalNetwork(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,3,strides=2,padding='same')
        self.bm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.relu = tf.kears.layers.ReLU()
    def call(self, x, training=True):
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.bm(x, training=training)
        return self.relu(x)
```

Instead of OriginalNetwork, I want to use the structure below.

```
def conv_block(channels, kernel_size, strides):
    layer = tf.keras.Sequential()
    layer.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(channels, kernel_size, strides=strides, padding='same'))
    layer.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    layer.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())
    return layer

class CleanNetwork(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        self.net = conv_block(32,3,2)
    def call(self, x, training=True):
        return self.net(x) # How to put training option??
```

But, how can I give the training options to batch normalization layer??

Comment: If you plan to call `model.compile`, `model.fit` and `model.predict`, don't worry about it. Tensorflow does it for you.

Comment: How about with GradientTape? I do not use model.compile due to the dataset issue